# Installing MoinMoin -wiki to my user directory on a server with no root access

Tags: installation, wiki, users

I posted this on webapps, but they told me to come here :)

I've been trying to install MoinMoin -wiki on this webserver, where I have no root access.
The server doesn't support wsgi, but it does support cgi/fcgi/etc.

I've scoured google for a simple guide on how to accomplish this, but the only guides I found were from the year 2004 or so. Other guides always assumed that one has root access.

So can anyone link a good tutorial for my question or just help me out here?

Your help is appreciated :)

P.S. Sorry if this is the wrong stack -page

edit: 
It's a Linux server, Ubuntu if I recall correctly cba to check now, as I think it's not relevant.
I want the wiki to end up in my public_html folder so that username.server.com/wiki would point to it.
I don't want to ask for them to open an extra port, though it is possible. I just want to get it over http and port 80.

Comment: what web server?

Comment: @ooshro It's an apache webserver

Answer (score 0):

For CGI support you can use Mac description:
http://moinmo.in/HowTo/MacOSXwithApacheServer

or Apache on Windows:
http://moinmo.in/HowTo/WindowsWithApacheServer

MoinMoin comes as well with its own standalone server implemented in wikiserver.py. You can start it on any non root **port > 1024** just via `$ python wikiserver.py` (by default port **8080**)

Comment: Sorry, it seems I wasn't specific enough on my question. Added more info.

Comment: for fcgi there is howto present as well http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/HelpOnInstalling/FastCgi